# How to use i% to create & assign symbols in one line?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The following code is resulting in an error:

```
    %i[@date @doctor @patient] = date, doctor, patient
```

However, this works:

```
    @date, @doctor, @patient = date, doctor, patient
```

How do I use %i to create the symbols and assign them values on the same line?

Comment: My method has 3 arguments: date, doctor, and patient. The purpose of the line is to create 3 instance variables for them, and assign them to their respective arguments. So date = 'a'; doctor = 'b'; patient = 'c';

Comment: `date = 'a'; doctor = 'b'; patient = 'c'; @date, @doctor, @patient = %i[date doctor patient]  #=> [:date, :doctor, :patient]`, so `@date #=> :date`,  `@doctor #=> :doctor`,  and `@patient #=> :patient`.

Comment: You said the latter works for you, so why do you want to add `%i[...]`? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

You can only assign values to variables (local variables, instance variables, class hierarchy variables, global variables, constants). `Symbol`s aren't variables, they are objects, therefore you cannot assign them values.